# Login using facebook sdk 3 fails on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, galaxy

A strange behavior occurs when I try to login on facebook through my app. This behavior, however, doesn`t show up on the emulator and on other two devices (Galaxy Y, with Android 2.3.5/2.3.6).

I want to publish some text on my wall. I click on the publish button and then it detects the user is not logged in, a dialog box is shown telling the user that my app wants to publish some information on my behalf. Until here, there`s nothing unusual.

The problem is that after the user presses the "Ok" button, a loading dialog appears and disappears right after. The facebook login screen is not shown and the user is not logged in either.

I receive one exception (which are inexistent on the other devices):

```
SpannableStringBuilder(24080): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Code:

```
private void OpenPublishingConnection() {
  if (Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, status);
  }
  if (Session.getActiveSession().isOpened() == false && Session.getActiveSession().isClosed() == false) {
    Session.getActiveSession().openForPublish(new OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_PUBLISH)).setCallback(status));
  } else {
    if (Session.getActiveSession().isClosed() == true) {
      Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList(PERMISSION_PUBLISH)));
    } else {}
  }
}
public void Publish(Bundle b) {
  OpenPublishingConnection();
  Request req = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", b, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
  RequestAsyncTask rat = new RequestAsyncTask(req);
  rat.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my app had some kind of conflict with the Facebook App, so I just uninstalled and reinstalled the latter and everything started working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't try another device

If you can no longer access your login email or phone number, and you don't have access to a device you've used to log into this account before, it's not safe for us to give you another way to log in.

We understand that this might not help you get back on Facebook, but we have to take this action to stop anyone who doesn't own this account from getting into it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).